# Can we programmatically change binding properties in XForms/Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have a binding in XForms document like following:

```
<xforms:bind id="fr-form-binds" nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')">
<xforms:bind id="section-1-bind" nodeset="section-1">
    <xforms:bind id="age-bind" name="age" nodeset="age" />
    <xforms:bind id="first-name-bind" nodeset="first-name"
        name="first-name"
        constraint="instance('fr-form-resources')//resource/section-1/first-name/alert/@show = false()" />
</xforms:bind>
```

Can we programmatically access (by XPath or something else) binding by its id and change constraint attribute in age-bind so that one doesn't need to write constraint like the one in first-name-bind and programmatically update the fr-form-resources?

Comment: You can't change the attribute itself, but there might be a way to do
what you want to do. Can you clarify "so that one doesn't need to
write constraint like the one in first-name-bind and programmatically
update the fr-form-resources"? It's unclear to me what you are really trying to get to.

Comment: I mean it would be great if we were able to change constraint in attribute with xpath or something instead of having a statically set constraint.

Comment: The closest I can think of is using `saxon:evaluate()` to evaluate an XPath expression created dynamically.

Comment: Excuse me but use evaluate() where? Simply put, what I want is not having 'constraint' attribute initially while being able to toggle control's alert afterwards.

Comment: You can't not have a `constraint` attribute and add it later, that's just not possible. But what you can have is `constraint="saxon:evaluate(some expression)"`, where "some expression" points to another element/attribute containing the XPath expression with the constraint. If this points to an element/attribute  containing e.g. `true()`, the constraint always matches, and you could set that to the default. And then if you change the value of the element/attribute to e.g. `string-length() gt 10`, then that expression with apply. So in effect you have a dynamic constraint.